# Including a conditional sql where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, where-clause, where-in

I'm trying to include a conditional where statement in my SQL code and i'm not sure exactly how to do it... currently it looks like this (see below) although i'm fairly certain that i'm going the wrong direction here.

```
     WHERE 
     [awb_prefix] in ('403','369')
     AND [agent_iata_code] NOT IN ('0508634')
     AND [yr] = 2014
     AND CASE WHEN [awb_prefix] = '369' THEN [origin_gw_carrier] in ('PO','9S','K4') ELSE [origin_gw_carrier] in ('PO','9S','K4','5Y')
     END
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute it yet?  Also, this is a pretty popular question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't what `CASE` is for.  You can try doing it like this:

```
WHERE   [awb_prefix] in ('403','369')
AND     [agent_iata_code] NOT IN ('0508634')
AND     [yr] = 2014
AND 
(
    ([awb_prefix] = '369' AND [origin_gw_carrier] in ('PO','9S','K4'))
OR  ([awb_prefix] <> '369' AND [origin_gw_carrier] in ('PO','9S','K4','5Y'))
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked perfectly, i didn't realize you could pair filter statements using parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the `case` use

```
AND 
(
    [origin_gw_carrier] in ('PO','9S','K4') AND [awb_prefix] = '369' OR
    [origin_gw_carrier] in ('PO','9S','K4','5Y')
)
```